# Wordpress prevent same image from loading twice

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I have wordpress page where I'm loading post images (on page load). If images are removed and loaded again via wp ajax request in my dev. tools I can see that same images are loaded twice. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour and have same images loaded once by different initiators? Or what is the right approach in this case?

[image]